# jQuery display CSV info on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have a `CSV` which I need to display on a page. I can do this via `$.get()` but once I have the `(data)` how can I separate it and allocate where to display it. Each line is separated by a `|`

Currently I'm using this code to display the info in a div:

```
$.get('feed.txt', function(data) {
$('div').html(data.replace(/\|/g, '<br>'));
});
```

I know this is probably a very big question to ask, so if anyone has encountered a good tutorial that would be awesome too.

**UPDATE**
Here is an example of the data I'm pulling in:

```
TYPE: Small, ID: 0001, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 12:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|
TYPE: Medium, ID: 0002, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 01:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|
TYPE: Large, ID: 0003, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 02:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|
```

Comment: what is the problem you having? I think you are doing it right and keep trying

Comment: Hi, once I pull in the data I dont know how to separate it. For instance in the sample data I have 3 lines. How would I display each of those lines in a separate div? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

**Try 1:**

I used `split()` to convert string to array delimited by `|` and loop each array value to add `div` element and send it to `$('div').html(values);`

```
$.get('feed.txt', function(data) {
    var arr = data.split('|');
    var values = '';
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      values += '<div>'+arr[i]+'</div>';
    }
    $('div').html(values);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d3spZ/2/

**Try 2:**

Here I used `replace()` function to warp `div` elements by replacing `|`.

```
$.get('feed.txt', function(data) {
    var new_data = '<div>'+data+'</div>';
    $('div').html(new_data.replace(/\|/g, '</div><div>'));​
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bwpjR/

Comment: Hi, one more question regarding this. How would I add a class to the generated div based on the info. For example the first line has type: small for that div I'd like to add a class of small. Thanks, I can start a new question if you want. Cheers

Comment: Yes, can do that. Use `search` function to find `Small, Big or Larger` and apply the class. You can post as a new question.

Comment: Thanks Muthu, I have added a new question with the title - jQuery add class to generated div based on csv info

Answer (score 0):

Just see if this work - http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/Eng8b

```
var data= "TYPE: Small, ID: 0001, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 12:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|TYPE: Medium, ID: 0002, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 01:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|TYPE: Large, ID: 0003, RESPONSE DATE AND TIME: 2012-12-12 02:00, UNITNAME: Name, MEMO : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.|";

var arr= data.split('|');
$(arr).each(function(index, element){
   $("#bd").append($("<div></div>").append(element));
});
​
```

**HTML**

```
<body id="bd"></body>​
```